# Trying to find the general temperature sensor of my CPU

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, sensors

I recently have downloaded this free-software called HWiNFO that lets me make graphs with the temperatures, and automatically does the average temperature of a sensor in a specific time, which I found very useful. But, I found that for my CPU, there are a lot of sensors, and I want the sensor that captures the general temperature of my overall CPU. I think it could be the Core Max, or the CPU Package, or CPU (PECI). Between the temps of the Core Max and CPU Package there is not a lot of a difference, but between these two and the CPU (PECI) there is a difference larger than 10 degrees.

Could you help me? Thanks.[Screenshot of the temperature sensors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao8bZ.png)

Comment: Package........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temperatures:

- Core #: Actual temperature of a particular CPU core.
- Core Max: The maximum temperature among all cores in the CPU.
- CPU Package: Shown on Intel CPUs, represents a 256-millisecond average value (calculated by CPU) of the hottest temperature sensor
  within the CPU package.
- CPU IA Cores: Maximum temperature among all computing (x86) cores in CPU (so part of CPU except Uncore and Graphics logic).
- CPU GT Cores: Temperature of the integrated graphics part of CPU (if present).

PECI (Platform Environment Control Interface):

- The main difference between PECI and other thermal monitoring methods is that **PECI
  reports a value expressing the difference between the current temperature and the
  thermal throttle point** (at which the CPU reduces speed to prevent damage due to
  overheating).

References:

- https://www.hwinfo.com/forum/threads/cpu-temp-sensors-explanation.5597/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Environment_Control_Interface